# Setting range with startCell.End(xlDown)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to change a data validation list range in my Excel Macro. Initially the whole C column has been selected manually and now I would like to change it dynamically in VBA.

My code:

```
Dim startCell As Range, firstNonEmptyCell As Range
Dim range1 As Range, rng As Range

Set startCell = Worksheets("Sel").Range("C2")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sel")

Set range1 = ws.Range("$C$2:startCell.End(xlDown).Address")
```

The line above is triggering the Runtime 1004 Error Application or object defined error

The rest of code is working if I hard code the startCell.End(xlDown).Address as $C$18 which is found actually as a return value of startCell.End(xlDown).Address if i check the debugger.

So I am not quite sure about the cause of this error in this case.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
Set range1 = ws.Range("$C$2:startCell.End(xlDown).Address")
```

with:

```
Set range1 = ws.Range("$C$2:" & startCell.End(xlDown).Address)
```

there may be other problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, the code with this modification is now working!